# Get empty string instead of null

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have null in a row if there no number. I need to put empty string in a row instead of null.

```
<td>${number}</td>. // null, if there no number,
```

so, Am I thinking in the right way? :

```
!number ? number : ""
```

Comment: Use  `number ?? ""`. Your version would at least need to have the `!` removed, but then for `number == 0`, it will not produce what you want.

Comment: You could also use number || '' but that would also give you an empty string for 0.

Comment: Your are in the right way

Comment: You was likely thinking `number ? number : ""`,  IOW: If a number return number, unfortunately 0 is also false,  so the modern way of `??` is much better, You could also be specific and check for null, `number !== null ? number : ""`,   but then what about `undefined`, that's why the `??` is much nicer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

**Working Demo :**

```js
let number = null;

document.getElementById('numberText').innerHTML = number ?? ''
```

```html
<p id="numberText"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check if the variable's type is number and if not it won't render anything:

```
typeof number === 'number' ? number : ''
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
`<td>${!number ? '' : number}</td>`
```

if there is no `number` then display `''` else display `number`